# Drag and Drop portlets in websphere portal 8

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, drag-and-drop

Anybody has experience dragging and dropping the portlets in websphere portal 8 standard layout. I am able to drag and drop in the static page but the standard page doesn't allow it. Any suggestions what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't missing anything - it's not allowed in the standard layout.